# serialize datatable with protobuff in C#

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

How to serialize datatable with protobuffer. I am trying like `Protobuff.serialize(dtDatatable);`
But it doesn't work.

Getting Exception ::

```
Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred: System.Data.DataSet
```

Comment: https://github.com/rdingwall/protobuf-net-data 
This can help you

Comment: Is there any way to serialize dictionary also?

Comment: @Pritam most standard dictionary types should just work out of the box; what is the dictionary *exactly* ?

Comment: @MarcGravell Dictionary is of <int,object>

Comment: @Pritam the issue there is the `object` - that doesn't play nicely

Comment: @MarcGravell object doesn't work. It throws exception.

Comment: @Pritam yes, I would expect it to. Very few serializers (typically: type-based serializers) are happy to work with `object`. protobuf-net has *limited* support, but frankly: I strongly suggest avoiding `object` here. `object` is not enough information for a serializer.

Comment: Anyway to serialize Untyped Datasets?